# Anchor Link in Main Menu Always Active on page with anchor

Tags: css, hyperlink, anchor, menuitem

I have an anchor link in my main menu that links to an anchor on the homepage. Problem is that when I am on the home page the anchor link is showing as active even though the anchor is halfway down the page.

[Anchor Link Permanantly Active on Home page](http://thegrapevineofflicence.com/)

Is it possible to apply a class to this that just displays it like the un active menu items or have i done something wrong with the anchor link?

I have tried multiple variations of .menu-item-106 a {} & .nav-menu .current_page_item > a, etc. but I can't get it right!

I'd appreciate if anyone can anyone help or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.menu-item-106 a:link, .menu-item-106 a :visited, .menu-item-106 a :active {....}
.menu-item-106 a :hover{...}

maybe?

Answer (score 1):

You can try add this jquery code for disable anchor hightlight, in the configuration menu, add extra class "anchor" in menus with achors.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var current =  $(".menu-main-menu").find(".anchor");
    $(current).removeClass("current-menu-item current_page_item");


});
```

Answer (score 0):

The following two css made the active page remove it and check

```
current-menu-item 
current_page_item
```

Comment: I'll give this a go too to see if I can get it to work out of curiosity thanks!